# meaning of rx_queue_*_csum_err and rx_fifo_errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ethtool

I am trying to debug some networking issue with one server. I monitor this machine with multiple monitors and I see that at times ping error rate jumps to 5/10%

I am running on ubuntu and I see that the output of ethtool -S eth0 shows positive values for rx_queue_*_csum_errboth rx_fifo_errors (a few thousands).

What do this counters actually track, are there any very well known causes for them to be non 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rx_fifo_errors` = Total number of rx_queue_*_drops

`rx_queue_*_drops` = Number of dropped packets per queue

Sounds like the RX interrupts aren't allocating buffers fast enough, resulting in the adapter dropping packets.

Check and increase the ring buffer.

```
# ethtool -g eth0
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:        4096
RX Mini:      0
RX Jumbo:     0
TX:        4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:         256
RX Mini:      0
RX Jumbo:     0
TX:         256
```

You can set your "`Current Hardware Settings`" for "`RX`" up to the limit shown in the "`Pre-set maximums`"

```
# ethtool -G eth0 rx 4096
```

**NOTE:** This setting will *not* survive a reboot. You may want to use `rc.local` (or something similar)

Comment: is the interface going to go down/up while changing this setting? i would run this on a production server so that would be quite inconvenient...

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli A Production server?  I doubt the NIC will go down. But *test it in Development/Non-Prod first* should be done for anything you do.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Linux kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/statistics.html):

`RX Queue Checksum errors` are indicative of physical link errors. Where as
`RX Fifo errors` are indicative of a FIFO overrun, as described by [@Signal15](https://serverfault.com/users/185661/signal15)

```
rx_crc_errors

    Number of packets received with a CRC error. Part of aggregate "frame" errors in /proc/net/dev.

    For IEEE 802.3 devices this counter must be equivalent to:

        30.3.1.1.6 aFrameCheckSequenceErrors
```

I would urge caution when adjusting the RX FIFO size on production machines, as I've experienced instability under certain configurations, such as: when the interface is part of a BRIDGE or BOND group.